# how to add 30 mins for current time

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.NET. I have a dropdownlist named `startTimeDDL`. Than I am using loop to enter in time inside that dropdownlist.

```
    ' Auto fill "Start Time"  for DropDownList
    Dim StartTime As DateTime = #12:00:00 AM#
    For i As Integer = 0 To 47
        StartTimeDDL.Items.Add(StartTime.ToString("hh:mm tt"))
        StartTime = DateAdd(DateInterval.Minute, 30, StartTime)
    Next
```

So look below and that will be inside the dropdownList. notie the format is hh:mm am/pm.

12:00 AM
12:30 AM
01:00 AM
01:30 AM
02:00 AM
...
11:30 PM

**Problem:**
lets say current time is 1:21:01 pm than I want to write code so it select 1:30 pm from dropdownlist. Now les take another example. les say current time is 12:00:00 AM than I was to select 12:30 AM from dropdownlist. les take one last example. les say current time is 2:10:12 AM than I want to  select 2:30 AM from the dropdownlist.

here is the code I wrote so far. problem with it is that I am only selecting the current time. now can I modfily to do what I want?

```
    Dim dDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")
    Dim temp As String = dDate
    StartTimeDDL.Items.FindByValue(temp).Selected = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round up if the minute value exceeds 30, round down if it's lower.

Here is an example implementation, you'll need to decide what to do with the "*exactly 30 minutes past the hour*" edge case. In my code it'll round up for that too.

```
Private Function RoundDateToHalfHours() As Date
    Dim current As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim ts As TimeSpan

    If current.Minute >= 30 Then
        ts = New TimeSpan(current.Hour + 1, 0, 0)
    Else
        ts = New TimeSpan(current.Hour, 30, 0)
    End If

    Return current.Date.AddTicks(ts.Ticks)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim roundedDate As DateTime = RoundDateToHalfHours()
StartTimeDDL.Items.FindByValue(roundedDate.ToString("hh:mm tt")).Selected = True
```

Answer (score 2):

You are playing fast and loose with DateTime when you should be using TimeSpan, some caution required.  The general way to round up an integral number to an arbitrary interval is

```
 roundedUp = interval * ((number + interval - 1) \ interval)
```

Which you can readily use on DateTime as well by converting it to ticks, a one-liner

```
Public Function RoundupDate(dt As DateTime, interval As TimeSpan) As DateTime
    Return New DateTime(interval.Ticks * ((dt.Ticks + interval.Ticks - 1) \ interval.Ticks))
End Function
```

Sample usage:

```
    Dim example = #2:10:12 AM#
    Dim rounded = RoundupDate(example, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30))
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't sure what you meant by a 'dropdownList'.  For this example I used a ComboBox.

```
    Dim StartTime As DateTime = #12:00:00 AM#
    'load combo box
    Do
        StartTimeDDL.Items.Add(StartTime.ToString("hh:mm tt"))
        StartTime = StartTime.AddMinutes(30)
    Loop While StartTime.TimeOfDay.TotalDays > 0

    Dim selectTime As DateTime = #2:10:12 PM# 'TEST  find this <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    'round time to 30 minutes
    Dim numSecs As Integer = (CInt(selectTime.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds) \ 1800) * 1800

    'the OP said 'les say current time is 12:00:00 AM than I was to select 12:30 AM"
    'so....
    numSecs += 1800 'round up 30 minutes ????????

    'create 'find'
    Dim ts As New TimeSpan(0, 0, numSecs)

    Dim findDate As New DateTime(ts.Ticks)

    StartTimeDDL.SelectedIndex = StartTimeDDL.FindStringExact(findDate.ToString("hh:mm tt"))
```